# Batch Script to Pause and Resume One Drive Sync?

Tags: batch, sync, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

Is there a batch script or other way to Pause or Resume OneDrive local sync? I have some folders that are synced on One Drive. But I do not want it to continuously sync. I would like to have a a script that can pause/resume the sync. Currently, I do it manually, but sometimes, it take a bit to get the Pause sync settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite a pause / resume script, but you can simply exit OneDrive by creating a shortcut or running:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" /shutdown
```

Which will effectively "pause" synchronising.

Then you can silently restart it with another shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\OneDrive.exe" /background
```

Where it will start merging changes again.

I can't remember where I found these switches originally, but there is a list of them [here.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/OfficeDocs-SharePoint/issues/2905)

Comment: I think that should work. Thanks a lot. Marked as Answer.

Comment: I found that 1) OneDrive command line switches must be all LOWER-CASE. e.g., Worked: "/background" and "/shutdown". DID NOT WORK: "/Background" and "/Shutdown". 2) Use combination "/background /shutdown" to prevent the File Explorer window popping up during shutdown.